# What happens if you use the command tar tvf as opposed to tar tvfz?

Tags: linux, tar

I am new to the world of Linux and in the process of setting up a Linux environment. I stumbled across the tar command as I need to view the contents of a file prior to extracting it and by accident ran the command tar tvf as opposed to tar tvfz. Is there any difference in running either command apart from the the fact that the z option is for gzip files?

Answer (score 2):

As you are new to Linux then it seems appropriate to point you at the help system which is the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/) command.

As to your question it appears that `tar` is smart enough to realise that you have passed it a compressed archive and will process it appropriately even without the z switch.

```
tar -tvf suphp-0.7.1.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x termi/termi       0 2009-03-14 18:08 suphp-0.7.1/
-rw-r--r-- termi/termi      13 2008-12-25 12:52 suphp-0.7.1/NEWS
-rw-r--r-- termi/termi    9416 2008-03-29 13:02 suphp-0.7.1/INSTAL
.
.
.
```

Note that if you use `tvfz` it will fail because a file has to follow the `f` switch

```
 tar -tvfz suphp-0.7.1.tar.gz
 tar: z: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

so you should use `tvzf`

Comment: Iain - Thanks I did read the man pages however was unsure if running the inappropriate command would have repercussions

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: As you are running it in `t` test mode it's only reading the file anyway so won't damage it.

Comment: Thanks. The article I am reading suggests that I run the command as tar tvfz - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-tar-command-examples/

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: If that works with your tar then please let me know which verion it is. `tar --version`

Comment: Iain - It is version 1.15.1. I am running the latest release of CentOS

Comment: Also, you can use the "j" switch instead of "z" when dealing with files compressed with bzip2 .

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference other than tar tvf will not be able to read a .tar.gz file, only a .tar file.

Comment: Please see my comment to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams